# Get record in in lightning component in communities

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, home-page-component

I want to created a component that would be used on a record detail page in a community
The component I created co far implements force:hasRecordId (and few more) but the id I get on run time in null.

```
flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,
forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes
```

What am I doing wrong. Is the feature only available for home pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `force:hasRecordId` as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation)

For the Experience builder the way I have managed to get the record ID is as below

Create an attribute

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

 <!--ATTRIBUTES DECLARATION -->

 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}"/>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getrecord}" />
 </aura:component>
```

Let's get the Id now in our JS controller

```
({
   getresults: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));//print the Id 
    
  }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately adding the entry in design and the default value didn't change anything. Console log still says "undefined":( My community in preview mode

Comment: Is it on the record detail ? .Also remember in builder parameter in admin mode  you will manually input that variable as "{! recordId}"

Comment: Thank you!!! that did the trick - {! recordId} in the builder

Comment: the only thing that is still broken is that the response I print in callback is not set on the component fileAction.setCallback(this,    function(response) {
         console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.sFileName", response.getReturnValue());
        });  I compared with examples on the web, checked for typos and I don't see why

Comment: that might be different one .Get the whole code in another thread so that can be worked

Comment: @MohithShrivastava this goes against the instructions set by SFDC [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm) right? "Don’t expose the recordId attribute to the Lightning App Builder—don’t put it in the component’s design resource. You don’t want admins supplying a record ID." Is there another way around this now?

Comment: @VMS check the other answer. That should be right way to do it

Answer (score 5):

force:hasRecordId is supported in communities, you can reference it in your component markup as follows:

```
{!v.recordId}
```

or fetch it as if it were an attribute from your controller as follows:

```
component.get('v.recordId')
```

Quick note, it has to be used in an object detail or record detail page within communities.

Comment: As of December '18 this method works. No need to create a design file.

Comment: I dont believe a design file was ever required iirc

Comment: Yeah... just putting this in there for future generations of devs that might try to use the other answer (by Mohith Shrivastava).